# multiple headers with grails excel-export

Tags: excel, grails, plugins

iam trying to create a file excel from database.

i tried to install this plugin.. https://github.com/TouK/excel-export

i tried to create a file excell..
this is my code..

```
def test={
        def city = City.list()
        def headers = ['City Name', 'Description']
        def withProperties = ['city', 'description']

        new WebXlsxExporter().with {
            setResponseHeaders(response)
            fillHeader(headers)
            add(city, withProperties)
            save(response.outputStream)
        }
    }
```

and the result like this..

[image]

now i am trying to create an excel file with multiple headers.

like this..

[image: ates]

for example :

```
H1  | class   |
H2  | student |
H3  | subjects|
---------------
```

and my excel will like this

```
H1  | class    |
H2  | student  |
H3  | subjects |
H1  | 1A       |
H2  | Milo     |
H3  | Math     |
H3  | Chemystry|
H3  | History  |
```

Comment: I think you might have to switch to using something like Apache POI for that kind of excel formatting.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore i think so, i am trying other plugin now... :(